# How can I change my commit to correct user in github?

Tags: github, account

At the beginning, I used other's account to do my work on github. Then my account is added into the organization, so I changed my account by using:

```
git config --global user.email "me@here.com"
```

In the commit page or issue page of any branch, the author is right. But in my dashboard, the commits is not mine. How can I solve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [the GitHub Help page "Set up Git"](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git):

> **Username**
>
> First you need to tell git your name, so that it can properly label
>   the commits you make.

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
# Sets the default name for git to use when you commit
```

You have only set your email, but first you should have set your name. That's probably why the author is not the right one in the dashboard.

**EDIT**

Since you already set your username as I suggested, you need to modify GIT_COMMITTER_NAME or GIT_AUTHOR_NAME variables.
In order to do so open a shell in your repository (if you're on Windows set the PowerShell as the predefined shell first from tools->options, so you can copy/paste in it) and type the following:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
```

Then open any texteditor and copy/paste the following in it:

```
an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    cn="Your New Committer Name"
    cm="Your New Committer Email"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    an="Your New Author Name"
    am="Your New Author Email"
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
```

Then modify the fields "cn", "cm", "an", "am" and the content of the two if statements accordingly, copy/paste this script into the shell and press enter twice.

This should solve your problem, but keep in mind that this is not a good practice when you share a repository with others, since it rewrites history.

See also the [Troubleshooting information here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git#troubleshooting) and the [GitHub Help page about changing author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info).

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say I had set the name already. And use the same command you gave me. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make my problem clear. I don't want to change my old commits' info since I do share a repository with others. What I want to do is committing my new changes with right user information. Can u help me with this?

Comment: Changing committer changes also history. If you want only the next commits to show the correct name, I fear this might be impossible (unless you want to commit and then do `git commit --amend --author "your_name your@mail"` everytime). Perhaps I'm wrong. However if you see that no one can help you here, your only hope is the GitHub support. If there is a way to do what you asked, they will know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, I had to change the credentials of the old user from the Keychain Access. Documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)

Comment: I don't see how Keychain Access relates to Git config. Would you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: Edited the answer to include doc link